# How can I properly render state values in a dynamic amount of rendered dropdowns?

Tags: reactjs

I want to render a dynamic amount of form rows. A new row can be added, and each row can also be removed after being added.

When adding form elements, populating them with data, and then removing an arbitrary row the dropdown values are not rendering properly, and do not reflect the true state of the element. Note: this doesn't occur for text inputs.

[Here is a sandbox that reproduces the issue](https://codesandbox.io/s/objective-cori-y9yp4d?file=/src/Form.js:0-1135)

**Form.js**

```
import { useState } from "react";
import FormUnit from "./FormUnit";

function Form() {
  const [formUnits, setFormUnits] = useState([
    { itemName: "", itemBinary: "" }
  ]);

  const handleAddFormUnit = () => {
    setFormUnits((prevUnits) => [
      ...prevUnits,
      { itemName: "", itemBinary: "" }
    ]);
  };

  const handleUnitChange = (e, idx) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;
    setFormUnits((prevUnits) => {
      const updatedUnits = [...prevUnits];
      updatedUnits[idx] = { ...updatedUnits[idx], [name]: value };
      return updatedUnits;
    });
  };

  const handleRemoveUnit = (idx) => {
    const updatedUnits = [...formUnits];
    updatedUnits.splice(idx, 1);
    setFormUnits(updatedUnits);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {JSON.stringify(formUnits)}
      {formUnits.map((unit, idx) => (
        <FormUnit
          key={idx}
          idx={idx}
          itemName={unit.itemName}
          onRemove={handleRemoveUnit}
          onChange={handleUnitChange}
        />
      ))}
      <button onClick={handleAddFormUnit}>add</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Form;
```

Which renders a user determined amount of FormUnit.js components:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import Select from "react-select";

function FormUnit({ itemName, onRemove, onChange, idx }) {
  const [dropDownSelect, setDropDownSelect] = useState("");
  const options = [
    { value: "yes", label: "yes" },
    { value: "no", label: "no" }
  ];

  const handleDropDownSelect = (option) => {
    const event = { target: { name: "itemBinary", value: option.value } };
    setDropDownSelect(option);
    onChange(event, idx);
  };

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <div>
        <input
          key={idx}
          type="text"
          placeholder="Name"
          value={itemName}
          name="itemName"
          onChange={(e) => onChange(e, idx)}
        />
      </div>
      <div>
        <Select 
          key={idx} 
          options={options} 
          onChange={handleDropDownSelect} 
          value={dropDownSelect}
        />
      </div>
      <button onClick={() => onRemove(idx)}>remove</button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default FormUnit;
```

It seems like the display is shifting the index positions down, eg

add four elements, set index 1 and 2 to "yes" and "no" respectively

[image]

remove the FormUnit at index 1 set to "yes"

[image]

The state correctly updates, but the index positions of 1 and 2 now show "yes" and "no" when it should display ['', 'no', '']

Note: I'm using react-select, but the issue persists with vanilla html

I've tried various things like adding a local state to FormUnit just for the dropdown selection, and rendering that as the value (and not doing this), or ensuring each Select element has an index, but it's made no difference.